# What is the "wtx-context" attribute, and why am I seeing it in HTML source?

Tags: html, attributes

I am noticing this attribute added to HTML source, I can't find any information about it.

It starts in the head tag:

```
<html wtx-context="8F1EE800-7352-408E-AC70-5297G5FD3F25">
```

It also appears in form elements and inputs.

Any information would be useful, such it's purpose and what it is thats inserting it and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, late answer. I browsed the web for this question too but didn't find anything useful.
It happens that I installed bitdefender a couple of days ago and guess what ? It's the culprit. Even if its extension is disabled, it adds this weird attribute. I completely uninstalled the plugin (not the AV) from my browser (chrome) and that's it.